# CheckMK 2.0.0p35 pnp4nagios graphs not working with Thruk 3.04

Tags: nagios, check-mk, thruk

Hello Thruk Community,

I have a CheckMK 2.0.0p35 RAW Edition working on Ubuntu 22.04.6 running Thruk 3.04 (latest release), I'm using pnp4nagios and livestatus integration just for reference as well.

My issue is only with the graphs displaying correctly within Thruk, I can confirm they display in CheckMK but for some reason I'm getting a 404 not found error.

It's probably something stupid/missed in my configuration as I'm relatively new to the latest Thruk build, but any help on this is greatly appreciated!

My two sense would be wherever Thruk in it's config files is probably pointing to wrong directory for the graphs to display.

Steps tried so far:

*changing thruk_local.conf file to see if graph settings can be configured in here based on the thruk instruction guides
*changing settings in CheckMK for the livestatus and integration settings
*restarting both CheckMK, Thruk, and sometimes a full reboot on laptop in case changes weren't applied successfully